# How to find full path of .exe file in Python?

Tags: python, path, operating-system, pathlib

I have to find full path of some .exe files in python. I've tried the following but this always outputs C:\Users\Admin\.

```
os.path.abspath("file.exe")
```

Comment: where are you "some .exe" files located and where are you running your python script. plz be more specific in this matter

Comment: I have to find path of a file with location - C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe using a python code. I used os.path.abspath("svchost.exe") but it's not giving a correct output.

Comment: it won't give you correct output because svchost is not in your current working path.
why do you want `svchost` ?

Comment: I want it's path for finding the file antivirus information through virustotal.

Comment: please join this [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215897/svchost-issue)

Comment: Unable to chat. It says must have 20 reputation.

Comment: Okay. so what's the approach you're following. We would want to know the overall picture so we know how you reached the `svchost` conclusion

Comment: FYI I think you'll have to use some windows specific python packages like `wmi` or `win32com` etc depending upon your python version. With that you can check the executor of your process. `svchost` in windows is responsible for execution so you'll get the path of the process executor. You'll need to run the script with admin privileges as `svchost` information is not accessible to all.

Answer (score 0):

Specifications please. Where is your python script running from and it location for better understanding.